# SwiftUI @Binding not updating in child

Tags: swift, swiftui

In my main view I have the following variable:

```
@State private var link = "https://www.google.com"
```

The view has two children that contain the variable's binding:

```
@Binding var text: String
```

, initialized like this: `Child(text: $link)`

Child 1 updates the variable, the parent receives the change, but Child 2 still keeps the first value

Comment: Please show your complete sample code as I cannot reproduce such situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a view to rebuild itself, you need to modify its state, environment object or observed object; those are the only things the view subscribes to.  If you just modify a binding the view has no way of knowing it needs to rebuild.  You should have the binding modify as a side effect either the environment, state or observed object of the view.  Since you have some shared state between children and a parent view and `@EnvironmentObject` seems like the right place to do it.

Comment: That wouldn't make any sense in the SwiftUI Paradigm. There should only be a single source of truth. A binding is derived from a state, thus the source of truth already exists in the original state.